# directly define objects in angularjs directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

controller

`$scope.options={autoplay:0}`

In HTML

`<my-directive datas=options></my-directive>`

In my directive

```
 app.directive('myDirective', [
    '$compile',
    function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          datas: '=?'
        },
        link: function(scope) {

          console.log(scope.datas.autoplay) // I am accessing options like this.
}}]
```

Instead doing like that optionally, Is there any way to do like this

HTML,

`<my-directive datas['autoplay']=1></my-directive>`

or

`<my-directive datas.autoplay=1></my-directive>`

but not like this

`<my-directive datas={'autoplay':1}></my-directive>`

or any other alternatives or changes to be made in directives to achieve this

Comment: You can do like `datas = {'autoplay': 1 }"`

Comment: That I did. can we use directly as I mentioned? Any way to do like that.

Comment: No, you can't. But why you want it in that way?

Comment: just to know. all possibilities. that's it